# Configure batabase for production/project managment

Tags: python, django, database

My ultimate goal is to create a Django based (so with Python) web application to handle production activities (at work).
In other words, something similar to the project management app, with different tasks for each project, etc.
But, before thinking about Django "world", I was thinking about how to define the underlying database.

First of all, let me explain what I mean.

Let's assume that I have to produce object OBJ1. To do that I have to complete a certain number of tasks, say TSK1, TSK2, TSK3. The same for OBJ2, OBJ3, and so on...
So, each "Object" has its own (different from object to object) sequence of tasks, with theirs own duration.
Now I may have to produce 5 pieces for OBJ1, 40 for OBJ2, and so on, and every "instance" of OBJx could have a different delivery date (tasks have different duration, from 1 hour to 7 days, for example, it depends).
I'd like to be able (at the end of the project) to add every OBJs to a page where I can update the tasks status, to control the progress and check for delay, and so on.

In the end... I'd like to be able to "handle":

- different project (obj)
- that can be repeated

I don't want to re-enter the same task for a repeated Object every time, so I was thinking to "build" a database with a table containing all the tasks for "Objects" (or Code as you like), with their duration and a flag with default value = 0 as it is not yet completed by default.

But after that? How can I "configure" the database to handle every Object?
I can't figure out how could be the structure of the database itself...

Maybe a second table that repeats the first one and an index for each Object?

I'm lost... probably I'm drowning in an inch of water.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe take a look to GenericForeignKey, You can setup a model task used by all your OBJ. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey

Comment: @bigfefi what about many-to-many?